# PHP - Array within an Array within an Array, and so on

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with a complicated Array and ultimately my goal is to get it into one simple array so I can insert each [record] into my database.

Given the complexity of the array, I can't wrap my head around how to flatten it out. I want to omit the [links] array and flatten out insert each [record] into the databse.

```
    Array
(
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [links] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => linkgoeshere
                                    [rel] => self
                                )

                        )

                    [record] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8ca9df0a2dfc72f3983ffc55c1dd1b9f459ae2fa
                            [timestamp] => 2020-09-28T10:30:59.98Z
                            [size] => 825
                            [fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [projectdescription] => Description Goes Here
                                    [projectvalue] => 650000
                                    [applicant] => Applicant name
                                    [specificusecategory] => Category
                                    [issuedate] => 2020-09-01
                                    [propertyuse] => Array
                                        (etail Uses
                                            [0] => R
                                            [1] => Transportation and Storage Uses
                                        )

                                    [buildingcontractoraddress] => Address Here
                                    [buildingcontractor] => ABC Co
                                    [typeofwork] => ASDF
                                    [year] => 2020
                                    [permitnumber] => 123456
                                    [bi_id] => 123456
                                    [applicantaddress] => address 
                                    [address] => address
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You may use recursion to traverse the array (with array_keys()) and write every entry where the value is no array into a new array which is handed through the recursion via call by reference. This solution would not work for duplicate keys. Any strategy how you want to work around them?

Comment: If this sounds useful to you and you need further assistance, I may post some more info or code, but it could contain mistakes as I have no way to test currently.

Comment: If you could share an example or help me with the logic, I would really appreciate it. Once I can wrap my head around it I can apply it to this array.

Comment: Did you mean [recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion)?

Answer (score 0):

I currently cannot test, but I hope that there are no syntax errors here:

```
function flatten($source, &$target){ // could also use call by reference for source for better memory management, but not needed
  foreach(array_keys($source) as $key){ // inspect all keys on current array
    if(is_array($source[$key])){ // recursively call for sub-array
      flatten($source[$key], $target);
    }else{ // copy value to new array, maybe add more logic for duplicates here as this code just overrides them
      $target[$key] = $source[$key];
    }
  }
}
```

Call this code with `$source` being the input and `$target` being the output. As the output is used as call by reference all function calls access the same output array.

You may add further logic to e.g. exclude the link array as you wanted.

Full demo code showing how to flatten an array:

```
<?php 
// Include this go get more warnings etc.
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function flatten($source, &$target){ // could also use call by reference for source for better memory management, but not needed
  foreach(array_keys($source) as $key){ // inspect all keys on current array
    if(is_array($source[$key])){ // recursively call for sub-array
      flatten($source[$key], $target);
    }else{ // copy value to new array, maybe add more logic for duplicates here as this code just overrides them
      $target[$key] = $source[$key];
    }
  }
}

$input =   Array( 0 => Array ("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3), "hello" => "world", 2 => Array());

print_r($input);

$output = Array();

flatten($input, $output);

echo "<br />";

print_r($output);
```

This gives me the output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 ) [hello] => world [2] => Array ( ) )
Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 [hello] => world )
```

Comment: When I use this and try to echo the data, it is blank. No errors though.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is get it so that the parent array is [records] then each record is an array within that and all sub-arrays are flattened into the [records] array.

Comment: Then you got other problems in your project. You cannot echo an array, this should give you a warning if you have enabled such php messages.

I tested the given function and it worked. I will provide a working full example in the answer above. Mind that your given array is syntactically incorrect (Strings not in "", no , between entries). Maybe this is the problem?

If you just want to flatten sub arrays then iterate over those and call the needed function on the records. I intended to give you an approach to flatten an array, not the specific integration into your project.